# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'register_form' available as request attribute Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Just needed a small help regarding Spring form functionality using spring. I am new to Spring form handling. I have created a register page functionality in which a user just enters his registration details and they are inserted into database. However after all set up code is written i am getting an error 'Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'register_form' available as request attribute'. I have checked several questions here and tried all things. I found my code is fine but still getting this error.

Please see my below files :

Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TestFactoryPat</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Application-context.xml, /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

   <listener> 
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>

   <servlet>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet> 

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">



    <!-- "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">-->

<bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
          p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactoryBean" />

<tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/springmvc"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>        
    </bean> 
     <bean id="sessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
       <!--<property name="mappingResources">
            <value>com.lnt.Pojo/Login.hbm.xml</value>                   
        </property>-->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
              <props>
                  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
              </props>
         </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"></property>
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="AuthenticateServiceBean" class="com.lnt.services.AuthenticateServices">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean"></property>
    </bean> -->

</beans>
```

MVC-Dispatcher servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.karan.TestFactory.Controller"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id = "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
    <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

    </bean>
    </beans>
```

My controller class for registration :

```
@Controller
public class RegisterController {

@Autowired
private BaseServices baseimpl;

    @RequestMapping(value="/submitRegistration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adduser(Registration_info register_form)  
    {
        baseimpl.saveorupdate(register_form);
        return null;    
    }
}
```

Registeruser.jsp page :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
        prefix="sec"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Test Registration</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h5> Registration Page</h5>

                <form:form id="RegisterForm" action="/submitRegistration" method="GET" modelAttribute="register_form">

<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>FirstName</td>
                        <td>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="register_form.firstName" size="30" />
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>LastName</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="register_form.LasttName" size="30" />
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email Address</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="register_form.EmailAddress" size="30" />
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Address</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="register_form.Address" size="30" />
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <td>
                                <form:input path="register_form.Phone" size="30" />
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Registration">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
            </table>
            </form:form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Please let me know if this issue can be resolved i have checked all my jar files also.

Comment: Not related to the concrete problem / exception : There is an invalid markup. You started `<table>` before `<form:form>` and closed inside `<form:form>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it won't fix the problem, you form submission method should be POST instead of GET.

With that in mind make the following changes to your code:

```
<form:form id = "RegisterForm" action = "/submitRegistration" method = "POST" commandName= "register_form">


@RequestMapping(value="/submitRegistration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adduser(@ModelAttribute("register_form") Registration_info register_form)
```

Comment: I think that the other issue you mentioned is because you have `</td>` right after the form tag